# Issue after react native expo eject: No visible @interface for 'RCTAsyncLocalStorage' declares the selector 'initWithStorageDirectory:'

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I just ejected from expo and everything went well but I'm now getting the following error when trying to run my ios app in Xcode :

> No visible @interface for 'RCTAsyncLocalStorage' declares the selector
>   'initWithStorageDirectory:'

Here is part of my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.17.1",
"expo": "^23.0.6",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"moment": "^2.20.1",
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.50.3",
"react-native-cloudinary": "^1.0.1",
"react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
"react-native-elements": "^0.18.5",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.3.0",
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
"react-native-image-to-base64": "^0.1.0",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^4.13.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.24",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.22",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
}
```

Comment: What version of react native are you using? This was fixed a couple of months ago. Were you using expo before or?

Comment: @Chanoch I created my app with the lastest version of expo about a month ago. I'll add all version to the thread.

Comment: Can I check if you are linking to the expo fork of the react native?

Comment: @Chanoch where can I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually managed to fix it, this is how:

I updated my "react-native" dependency to the latest one available:
"https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-23.0.0.tar.gz"

I removed all dependency that I had installed by mistake in my previous expo app that actually required react-native link using the npm uninstall --save command:
react-native-image-to-base64, react-native-cloudinary

Then I also had to remove them from the General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries
Now it works! I'm having issues with the Facebook Login now but at least it doesn't crash my app.

Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

I feel really dumb for not realizing it sooner, but I had this issue when I forgot to run `yarn` after switching branches with a different Expo version.

Hope that saves someone else some debugging.